# Glassfish JDBC lookup jindi

Tags: jdbc, glassfish

I created a "JDBC Connection Pools" and a "JDBC Resources" called myDB (JINDI name).

How to access this in my webapp?

I tried:

```
<ejb-ref>
<ejb-ref-name>myDB</ejb-ref-name>
<lookup-name>myDB</lookup-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

And how to access it in the code?

I tried:

```
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    com.sun.appserv.jdbc.DataSource ds = (com.sun.appserv.jdbc.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
     Connection con = ds.getConnection();
     Connection drivercon = ds.getConnection(con); //get physical connection from wrapper
     Statement stmt=null;

     stmt = con.createStatement();
     stmt.executeUpdate("Update");
     // Do db operations.
    // Do not close driver connection.
    stmt.close();
    con.close(); // return wrapped connection to pool.
```

Or like this?

```
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?"
    + "user=admin&password=admin");
```

I am irritated. I just want to access my relational db to select and insert things.

Comment: How did you create the jdbc connection pool?

Comment: over the admin console: resource-type: java.sql.driver and driver class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    .... the ping succeeded